# Summing randomly placed integers throughout text using Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I have a text file with some lines like so:

"This is 10 some 4 generic text.

It doesn't 4 matter 5 what it says 1

I'm just using it,

To make 2 a 2 point."

I'm trying to find the sum of the numbers dispersed through the text using re.findall. So far I have:

```
import re

handle=open('.txt')

for line in handle:

    num = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if len(num)>0:
           num = list(map(int, num))
           total = sum(num)
```

And that's as far as I can get. Using re.findall assigns num a series of lists of string integers (['10', '4'], ['4', '5', '1'], [], ['2', '2']). Len filters out lines that contain no numbers (['10', '4'], ['4', '5', '1'], ['2', '2']). List(map()) converts the lists from strings to integers ([10, 4], [4, 5, 1], [2, 2]), and assigning sum(num) to total sums each list ([14], [10], [4]). From here I'm trying to sum these three numbers. I guess what I'm looking for is sum(total(sum(num))) but Python doesn't like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to apply the regex every single line:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: txt = """This is 10 some 4 generic text.
   ...:    ...:
   ...:    ...: It doesn't 4 matter 5 what it says 1
   ...:    ...:
   ...:    ...: I'm just using it,
   ...:    ...:
   ...:    ...: To make 2 a 2 point."""

In [3]: sum(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", txt)))
Out[3]: 28
```

So with a text file, this should work:

```
import re

with open("input.txt", "r") as handle:
    print(sum(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", handle.read()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tt = ([14], [10], [4])
print (sum(i[0] for i in tt))
#28
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily without reading the text line by line.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
with open('.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    summation = sum(int(x) for x in pattern.findall(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [read](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) without an argument and the entire contents of the file will be read and returned. Then findall will return a list of strings which you could map to an int and then sum the whole list.

But your regex will match digits throughout the whole content, also for example `2x + y`, `k8s` and `z3`

You could update your regex to use a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind to assert that what comes before and what comes after is not a non-whitespace character:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pHAA1w/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mwMVpG)

For example:

```
import re
with open('text.txt') as handle:
    total = sum(map(int, re.findall(r"(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)", handle.read())))
    print(total)
```